# ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: angular4-httpclient

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5yrs.png)i have call Post/Get api when running app they show me error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT in angular4

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. In order for us to help you, you need to improve your question. read [ask] and provide code/logs. Not screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Either your internet connection is interrupting (most of the time faced by me when using mobile data tethering) or the server you are connecting is busy so that your request is in a queue or rejected at the network level of the server.

Comment: Unable to connect to server from Cordova Ionic application

Comment: @PawanArora are you able to open that URL in browser or another client (like telnet). I am unable to open in browser or telnet (but this could be because I am not in your network). The message means clearly the server is not reachable from your application regardless within application or IDE or anything else...